# PHP Object change after calling call_user_func_array, but variable is not

Tags: php, variables, reference

I am trying to build a custom event management.
However, I have something need help. Please check following code I did:

```
class A
{
    public $a = array();

    public function setA($value)
    {
        $this->a[] = $value;
    }
}

class B
{
    public function hook($arg)
    {
        $arg->setA('5');
    }

    public function hook2($arg)
    {
        $arg[] = 'my name';
    }
}
$a = new A();

call_user_func_array(array(new B, 'hook'), array($a));

var_dump($a->a);

$name = array();
call_user_func_array(array(new B, 'hook2'), array($name));


var_dump($name);
```

Here is what I see on my sceeen:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '5' (length=1)

array (size=0)
  empty
```

You can see object a was changed but array $name is not. I passed values to call_user_func_array, not reference.

I am abit confused by that. Can anyone explain how does it work?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object are always [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.references.php) (kinda - it's more like a copy of the identifier of the object), unlike other types, like array, that doesn't. To passing the parameter [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), use the `&`:

```
public function hook2(&$arg)
{
    $arg[] = 'my name';
}
```

Then call it with

```
call_user_func_array(array(new B, 'hook2'), array(&$name));
```

Comment: Thanks Federico for your answers.Yes I know how to pass the array as reference. But I do not understand why object always passed by reference ?